# Chilkat + codeSigning

Tags: vbscript, code-signing, chilkat

As so far I was using "[CAPICOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/getting-ready-to-use-capicom)" for code signing.
But currently using "[Platform SDK Redistributable: CAPICOM](http://%20Platform%20SDK%20Redistributable:%20CAPICOM)" link to get this SDK you will see `We're sorry, this download is no longer available.`.

So I was curious what other code signing possibilities are.
As I have a license for the Chilkat software, I was wondering how to use this code signing software.

For this moment I only found this 8 year old answer:
http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/3757/code-signing

And this reference documentation:
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatCertRef.html#prop8

But no one examples.

**Could somebody help me how to use Chilkat component for codeSigning ?**

ps.
For my best would be VBScript example, if not then any other will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code signing functionality would require inserting the signature (Authenticode Signature Format) into the Windows PE File Format.  Although Chilkat has the ability to create PKCS7/CMS signatures, there is no implementation at this time to do the PE insertion.   If Chilkat does it in the future, you will find methods and examples explicitly for code signing.

(The ForCodeSigning property of a Certificate is just an indication of the intended usage of a certificate.  It does not imply code signing ability.)

Comment: I saw that you recently added signing for PDF... so .... Could you add this (code signing) on your's TODO LIST ?

Comment: It's on the list, but the list is a mile long.   :)